# Get Number of visits on all Product SKU using Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

```
function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
        $optParams = array(
            'dimensions' => 'ga:productSku',

            );
        $k = $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $profileId,
            '2014-01-03',
            '2014-06-03',
            'ga:productDetailViews',
            $optParams);

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($k);
        echo "</pre>";
        die();
    }
```

I am using this function trying to get visits on all product sku. It only shows me one with zero views. How to do it correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to enable Enhanced Ecommerce, and update your tracking code to get data for Product Detail View. Take a look at Google's documentation on [Product Detail Views](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-detail-view).

For example, on all of your product detail pages, you will have to add this code:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
ga('require', 'ec', 'ec.js');

ga('ec:addProduct', {
  'id': 'P12345',
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt',
  'category': 'Apparel',
  'brand': 'Google',
  'variant': 'black'
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```